# How do you analyze why generic apps bring in a decent income?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development

If this is the wrong place, point me to the right one. Thanks.

I come across *about me* pages showing people who show themselves travelling, having children, maybe owning houses, motorbikes, teslas.

The commonality is that they are high in maintenance cost and general cost.

If you didn't have a steady income, you could not sustain them.

Of course, I am curious about their occupations.

Most often they are CTO or CEO of online companies, like app developers.

The apps themselves are sand-grains in the sahara: generic apps like meal planners or route planners. Nothing fancy that I could discern. Also not on top of any list, by far not on the level of an instagram app.

I also tried to make an app of me famous, yet it became just another sand-grain in the sahara.

Yet they have employees they have to pay. They have houses and other constant expenses, as I showed. And they have been active for years like that.

I want to know what I don't see, so I can replicate this.

How do you analyze why generic apps bring in a decent income?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116620/discussion-on-question-by-percival-junghans-how-do-you-analyze-why-generic-apps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't. It's a bit like the survivorship bias, because you see a handfull (by comparison) of people that "made it", but not the thousands of developers that made something equally and are still not rich by any definition.

Also evaluate that competition is everywhere. You might be asking why even smaller villages have multiple brands of supermarkets whilst they mostly sell the same stuff.

If you want some form of idea the best thing to do would be to create a feasibility study and do some decent marketing research. What kind of competitors are there? What are their strengths and weaknesses? etc. etc.

Do note that there is guarantee for succes ever.

Comment: The correct answer is indeed simply "survivorship bias".  (You can completely ignore downvotes on this site.)

Comment: Possibly downvoted because it's an answer to a question that was likely to be closed. Not a downvoter myself.

Comment: Survivorship bias is a fancy way of saying "luck". But luck is always preparation + opportunity. You do not know which weighed higher. So how do I determine his preparation?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to call yourself a CTO/CEO of an app company that **doesn't** make a worthwhile income, and any one of the following may be true:

- they made their money in a previous role and are semi-retired
- they have a main role elsewhere and the app, which takes little maintenance, is a side hustle
- the app is a vanity / portfolio project
- it's all false or misleading anyway

Until you've seen the company finances, you're purely taking their word for it!

Comment: This question is very broad and is quite opinion-based (besides that it has little to do with WP) - on SO users are discouraged to answer such questions - instead they should be flagged/vtc - is there a different approach here on TWP?

Comment: @iLuvLogix If this is the wrong place, point me to the right one. Thanks.